# Hide name of the user and computer name from terminal window title

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, zsh

Before `Catalina` it was possible to hide username and computer name from terminal window title:

[image]

Yet now despite any combination of configuration I'm unable to hide those items from window title:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is because you are running zsh shell. I'm running the bash shell and no name or directory shows up in terminal window name. You can run bash before running terminal and that should give you the window name you want.  If you type zsh the terminal name will change back.

I don't have Catalina but I've read its changed initial terminal setting to zsh.

Comment: Yes, I deliberatelly switched to `zsh` because it's now a default for MacOS, I thought that probably window configuration has nothing to do with version of shell that is used.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the **Preferences** in the **terminal** (top right)
2. Go into the **Shell** tab
3. Then copy/paste the command

   ```
   export PS1="\W \$"; clear;
   ```
4. Uncheck the "**Working directory**", "**Active Process**", and everything else under the **Title section.**
5. Then restart the terminal and should work. 
   [image]
   [image]

The final look will be like this

[image]

Comment: This is solution for `bash` shell, I'm using `zsh` though